# Building two build.gradle files, error in file path of the second build.gradle

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have an angular frontend project and a springboot backend project in two different folders. Each one has his own **build.gradle** file.

Here they are :

frontend :

```
group 'X'

apply plugin: "com.moowork.node"
apply plugin: "java"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven{
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0"
    }
}

task clientBuild(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['run', 'build']
}

build.finalizedBy('clientBuild')
```

backend :

```
group 'X'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'admin'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

task buildAngular(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'D\\myProject\\workspace-dev\\myProjectFront\\build.gradle'
    tasks = ['build']
}

build.finalizedBy('buildAngular')
```

When I execute my backend build file I want my frontend to be executed too. The thing is I got this error on the `buildFile property` on `buildAngular task` :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':admin:buildAngular'.
> File 'D:\myProject\workspace-dev\myProjectBack\d\D\myProject\workspace-dev\myProjectFront\                                                                           
build.gradle' specified for property 'buildFile' does not exist.
```

Somehow my path is taking as input "where I am in cmd" + buildFile path, any idea about how to correct that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try writing this

```
buildFile = 'D:\\myProject\\workspace-dev\\myProjectFront\\build.gradle'
```

instead this

```
buildFile = 'D\\myProject\\workspace-dev\\myProjectFront\\build.gradle'
```

Try adding a colon.